# seo friendly url`s - how to?

Tags: php

In my website I have a form from which the users can choose to search for specific title in news database. 
They can choose main rubric (for example Businnes) and subrubric (for example Local)and after that to enter some string to search. 
After they submit the form the webpage returns the requested infromation and the url looks like this.

```
foo.bar/1001/234/
```

where 1001 is id of Businnes  and 234 is id of Local

How to do so id`s to be replaced by relevant names ?

```
foo.bar/Businnes/Local/
```

Comment: Does your site support foo.bar/Businnes/Local/ names already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using apache/htaccess/mod_rewrite, then handled by PHP

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

From there you need to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse out the data you need.

The first line turns on the rewrite engine.

The second 3 lines says, `if the requested file or directory does not exist, send the request to index.php`

You can just explode the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the parts of the data you need, no regex required.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an rewrite name for each zour record ( may be unique and apostrofs, spaces etc. free ) - use regexp for cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) - there is quite a handy [generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/) for simple rewrites if you don't know [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) well

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Apache webserver - which i am assuming you are, then you need to look into MOD Rewrite.

There is a good tutorial that I have bookmarked here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Answer (score 0):

is it? http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html / answer 2